# How to save content of textView in android listview while scrolling

Tags: android

`public class AttendanceActivity extends Activity {

```
TextView rollNo, name, attendance,attendance1,tv;
SqliteDBHelper db;
private List<Student> studentlist;
private List<Attendance>Attendancelist,attendancelist;
private String status;
ImageView iv;

ArrayList<String> mannschaftsnamen = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> namelsist = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> idintegr= new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<NameBean> beanList=new ArrayList<NameBean>();
BaseAdapter myAdapter = new BaseAdapter() {

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView rollNo;
        TextView name;
        TextView attendance;
        TextView tv;

        }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder viewHolder;




        if(convertView==null){

            // inflate the layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.attendance_layout, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.rollNo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rollNoTxtView);
            viewHolder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTxtView);
            viewHolder.attendance = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.attendanceTxtView);


            // store the holder with the view.
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

        }else{

            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }



        if(convertView != null) {


            viewHolder.name.setText(studentlist.get(position).getStname());
            viewHolder.rollNo.setText(Integer.toString(studentlist.get(position).getSregno()));

            //viewHolder.attendance.setText(status);
            viewHolder.attendance.setText("P");

            viewHolder.attendance.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(12, 107, 12));



                        }

        return convertView;

    }




    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return studentlist.size();
    }
};

ListView list;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_attendance);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    final String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
    // Now formattedDate have current date/time
    //      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), formattedDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    tv.setText(formattedDate);

    TextView columnHeader1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.column_header1);
    TextView columnHeader2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.column_header2);
    TextView columnHeader3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.column_header3);
    TextView sub=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.subname);
    iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.home);
    columnHeader1.setText("Regno");
    columnHeader2.setText("Name");
    columnHeader3.setText("Attendance");
    db = new SqliteDBHelper(this);
    int value2 = getIntent().getIntExtra("uidr",0);
    String subname=getIntent().getStringExtra("subname");
    sub.setText(subname);
    studentlist=db.getStudentName(value2);
    //String name1=db.getStudentName1(value2);
    //Attendancelist=db.getAttendanceDetail(name1);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);


    list.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, final View view, final int position,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            TextView tv = ((TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.attendanceTxtView));



            Log.d("textview", "text" +tv.getText());
            if(tv.getText().toString().equals("P"))
            {
                tv.setText("A");
            //  tv.setTextColor(Color.rgb(200,0,0));
                tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(200, 0, 0));
            }
            else
            {
                tv.setText("P");
            //  tv.setTextColor(Color.rgb(12,107,12));
                tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(12, 107, 12));
            }
            String attendance1 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.attendanceTxtView)).getText().toString();
            int id= Integer.valueOf(((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.rollNoTxtView)).getText().toString());

        db.updatedetails(attendance1,id);
            //  String message = view.findViewById(R.id.attendanceTxtView).gett().toString();
            //    Toast.makeText(Activityname.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ImageButton confirm = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.confirm);
            confirm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AttendanceActivity.this);

                    // Setting Dialog Title
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Please verify the attendance");

                    // Setting Dialog Message 
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Have you confirmed " );

                    // Setting Icon to Dialog
                    /* alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);*/

                    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
                    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

                             TextView tv;
                              View view;
                            for (int i = 0; i <= list.getLastVisiblePosition() - list.getFirstVisiblePosition(); i++)
                            {

                                 tv = (TextView) list.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.attendanceTxtView);
                                 int id= Integer.valueOf(((TextView) list.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.rollNoTxtView)).getText().toString());

                                    String name1=((TextView) list.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.nameTxtView)).getText().toString();
                                  if (tv!=null) {
                                     mannschaftsnamen.add(String.valueOf(tv.getText()));
                                     idintegr.add(id);
                                    namelsist.add(name1);

                                     Log.e("ypgs", String.valueOf(tv.getText()));
                                     Log.e("ypgs","" + id);
                                     Log.e("ypgs", name1);

                            }
                            }

                            for(int i=0;i<namelsist.size();i++)
                            {
                                Log.e("ypgsinaloop", namelsist.get(i));
                            }
                            db.insertdetails1(namelsist,idintegr,mannschaftsnamen);




                        }   

                    });

                    // Setting Negative "NO" Button
                    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // Write your code here to invoke NO event
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ok,please verify again..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

                    // Showing Alert Message
                    alertDialog.show();
                }
            });




        }
    });


}
```

}
`I have list item with TextView in it, I have a problem when I click on "P" it changed to "A",But after scrolling from top to last again when i came to top position it become "P".

Please refer my image for  understanding my problem

[image]

Comment: I didn't find any image @alokraj. Please provide that.

Comment: now i attached image.please help me  if you know

Comment: Please provide your adapter code here.

Comment: I have attached my full code only.@rahul

Answer (score 0):

You should store the values in an array according to the positions:

```
public static final ArrayList<String> changed_keys = new ArrayList<>();
```

and then in the `getView` method in the adapter check:

```
if(array.get(position).equals("p")) 
{
    textView.setText("p");
}
else
{
    textView.setText("a");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> OnItemClick, Change ArrayList value also with textview updation, and
>   after changing,

call `adapter.notifyDataStateChanged();` method

> In adapter keep checking this condition.

```
  if(array.get(position).equals("p")) 
    {
        textView.setText("p");
    }
    else
    {
        textView.setText("a");
    }
```

Hope it will help you !

Comment: why we need to check condition .@rahul

Comment: because, after clicking on listitem, you do changes in TextView, at the same time you need todo changes in your ArrayList, and after that you need to call adapter.notifyDataStateChanged() method, so at that moment, again adapter is notified, so data which is displayed on screen will be updated.. that is why you need to check condition, so whenever listview scroll, it will autamatically take updated value from ArrayList !

Comment: sorry guys, i have tried all the solutions  but not able to do.can anyone help me.

Answer (score -1):

Listview items are constantly destroyed and recreated when scrolling. The thing you need to do here is to save state of every item when created and reuse it whenever you are at that position again.

Edit:
in your adapter's getView method you could do something like this:

```
   String[] stringStateList;
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

//inflate convertView
       TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textview);
        textView.setText(stringStateList[position]);

            return convetView;
        }
```

In here you can fill your stateList in constructor of your adapter or you could use a map instead.

And in your onItemClickListener:

```
stringStateList[position]=textView.getText.Tostring();
```

Comment: yes dude ,can you provide me some example or sample code @ pedif

Comment: can anyone please help me on this.